# How to prevent users from navigating to symfony project directories?

Tags: symfony

How to prevent users from navigating to symfony project directories?

I see vendor directory content when I visit:

```
http://localhost/myproject/vendor/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [configure](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) your web server's document root directory to /web folder to avoid this issue. Sample configuration snippet for Apache:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/project/web
<Directory /var/www/project/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Please don't post just link only answers, rather also copy paste the necessary part to solve the issues and include it in here.